# how to get the size of disabled attribute in table with xpath in selenium-java

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the amount of columns in a specific table, but there are disabled attribute -  and i would like to know if it is possible to get the size of it without the disabled ones(the amount of the displayed columns in the table).

as you can see some of the  tds are disabled in the attached picture.
The command i tried to work with is:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*/table[@id='TABLE NAME]/tbody/tr[2]/td[@style='display:none;']")).size()
```

the issue is that the `style='display:none;'` might not work in future tables because the value will be different for disabled tds.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean you want the size of only visible ones and not the disabled ones

Comment: Yes, i would like to have the size of the visible ones.

Comment: can you plz post the full source code then so that i can prepare a working code thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but i can not provide it at the moment, can you please try to assist me through some example ? You can see the attached pic above and see all the visible and hidden <td>'s...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To return the visible ones, you could use `not` and `contains` in your XPath:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("id('table-id')/tbody/tr[2]/td[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]")).size()
```

Or with a CSS selector:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#table-id > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:not([style*='display:none'])")).size()
```

Another way would be to filter all the elements with `WebElement::isDisplayed` :

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#table-id > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td"))
  .stream().filter(WebElement::isDisplayed).count()
```

Comment: For your answer you've used style='display:none;'.. I'm trying to see if it is possible to get the size without using a specific attribute like it in order to show only the visible ones.

Comment: No, I've used `style*='display:none'` which will be true if the style contains `display:none`.

Comment: I've added another example to get the count of the visible elements by filtering them. Note that it will be slower depending of the number of elements.

Comment: yeah i understand how you used the display:none, but my question was is there any chance that in future html tables i will find hidden tds that might have different value in style attribute? If so your answer can solve it only for this specific table (because of the style value)...i'm trying to understand if your answer is relevant to any html table i will have in the future. Thanks alot !